# Redundant keyword arguments

Tags: python, methods

I found that writing a function which is a wrapper around another one can lead to "redundant" keyword arguments. For example look at this few lines:

```
def check_then_execute(foo=1, bar="A"):
    foo = safe(foo) # will return foo in a safe form
    bar = safe(bar) 
    execute(foo=foo, bar=bar) # doesn't it feel redundant?
```

In this example `execute()` is a library function that has keyword arguments. Possibly more than two.

Is there a way to pass keyword arguments using the name of the variable as the keyword?

Comment: I don't see nothing redundant here, your code should be as obvious and predictable as possible, if you don't want to pass parameters by keyword -- pass them positionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach would be:

```
execute(**some_dict)
```

Now, how you get to a usable `some_dict` that is less verbose than simply repeating the arguments depends on your situation. In your case, if you accept *positional* arguments for `check_then_execute`:

```
def check_then_execute(*args):
    safe_args = dict(zip(('foo', 'bar'), map(safe, args)))
    execute(**safe_args)
```

This is… maybe… less verbose…? You be the judge.

If you're accepting keyword arguments, it's actually slightly shorter:

```
def check_then_execute(**kwargs):
    execute(**{k: safe(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()})
```

If you want to accept any mix of positional and keyword arguments… you're probably better off doing what you're doing, possibly slightly condensed:

```
def check_then_execute(foo=1, bar='A'):
    execute(foo=safe(foo), bar=safe(bar))
```

Comment: Actually I started on this path with `execute(**dict)`, and not found a way to make the dictinory in a way I feel not too verbose (maybe that's a better word). If there would be a way to create a dict by using a name of the variable I could make a custom dict with `d.add(myvar)`. The realization would be: `d[var.__name__]=var`

Comment: I suppose you could dick around with `locals()`, but none of that will be any easier than just repeating the name.

Comment: Why not just use both args and kwargs? `def check_then_execute(*args, **kwargs):`, then `new_args = map(safe, args)` and `new_kwargs={k: safe(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()}`, then you can just call `execute(*new_args, **new_kwargs)`.

Comment: @ymbirtt 'Cause that's way more complicated than `foo=safe(foo), bar=safe(bar)`…!? And it's not clear from the question whether `*args` can be passed as args; if they could, this question would be moot.

Comment: True, it is more complicated than `foo=safe(foo)`, but we know that this simpler method would look real ugly and be full of duplication if there were 5 args. As for whether `*args` can be passed or not, I don't think that's a problem. What OP is after seems to be a new function which calls the old function, but with `safe` called over each of its arguments. Whether those arguments are named or positional is irrelevant when you just use `*args, **kwargs`. From outside this function, it's exactly like calling the functions from the library, but with your added guarantees of safety.

Comment: @ymbirtt Well, again, the question is specifically about `foo=foo` being redundant. There are many situations where that could be the case, this kind of function wrapper is probably just an example. If you could just pass `execute(foo, bar)`, there would be no problem here. I've tried to illuminate the general approaches you can take here, and sometimes `foo=foo` *is* the least verbose solution, which is also important to highlight.

Comment: Yes, the question is specifically about `foo=foo`. It can also occur in `"this is {foo}".format(foo=foo)` I guess this was the motivation behind f-strings.